# Focusing of cell is not working after inserting of new column in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have inserted a column between E and F after I clicked a button. Please see my code below:

```
 Columns("E:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

After that, I wanted the user to click on the cells that were added recently (Column E). But, when I clicked on the new added cells, I cannot see the borders on focused around the cells.

[image]

[image]

On the first image, in cell E8, I can see a border (colored green) when i clicked it. But, on the second cell, on E7, I cant see the border. This is important for me to serve as a guide for the user.

Any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Check the `Merge` button status on your Excel Task Bar when you have clicked on E7

Comment: it is disabled when I clicked it..

Comment: OK, and then you click E7, in the White box next to the Function/Formula bar above your Sheet, does it only say E7

Comment: Yes it is.. I can only see E7 on the box

Comment: If you use your keyboard arrows to navigate from E8 to E7, does it become selected? Also, why is your cursor green?

Comment: I can navigate from E8 to E7, and the name changes also, BUT the cell is not selected. It is green because I am using excel 2013

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96113/discussion-between-jean-pierre-oosthuizen-and-smz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: I am Using Office 2010**

With my Version I am not able to select cells which ave been set to locked when the document is protected.

It might be that in Office 2013 you are able to select the cell but the Rectangular Cursor will be hidden when the Cell is selected to Locked, depending on your settings for the document Protection.

Setting the Locked/Hidden Property of a Cell, right click Cell and Select "Format Cells...":

[image]

When you protect your document there will be two Settings selected by default. To Protect the document Click the Review Tabs and Select "Protect Sheet". See below:

[image]

Check Settings are selected in the Protect Sheet window, this might advise you as to where the issue is coming from.